# PBI cluster column visual - hide when value is zero

Tags: powerbi

I have a clustered column chart showing items expiring in the next 6 months, the value will change as and when data is refreshed, can I automate the visual to hide the month that has zero values, in this example, I want to show July, Aug, Sep and Oct only.  Then when data is refreshed, the months that has values may change and I want the visual to be able to change automatically to hide those months with zero values.  Is this possible?, if yes, how?  [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For say, you have this below output-

[image]

Now, you can set filter as below and output will meet your expectation-

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just make a new measure (or edit the current one) that forces zero-values to be evaluated as `BLANK`. This is a good use-case for the recently added `IF.EAGER` function.

```
New Measure :=
IF.EAGER ( 
    [Old Measure] = 0 ,
    BLANK () ,
    [Old Measure]
)
```